# Search MySQL using PHP and a variable located in HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make php search my database of parts by a part number that is generated in the html page and then output the price into a cell.
Here is my Ajax script and variable

```
var Row = document.getElementById("test2");
var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
$myPartNumber = Cells[1].innerText;

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "http://localhost/filenamehere.php",
data: { Part_Number : $myPartNumber },
dataType: 'html',
async: true,
success: function(data) {
    $('#price').html(data);
}
});
}
```

Here is my PHP code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nipple_list where Part_Number='$myPartNumber' ");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>LDS Price $</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['LDS_Price_$'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I keep getting errors and warnings like

> Notice: Undefined variable: myPartNumber in C:\Apache24\htdocs\filenamehere.php on line 10

Comment: change `"SELECT * FROM nipple_list where Part_Number='$myPartNumber' "` to `"SELECT * FROM nipple_list where Part_Number='$_POST['Part_Number']' "`

Comment: Also you should be using prepared queries.

Comment: I got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\filenamehere.php on line 10

Comment: Sorry this `"SELECT * FROM nipple_list where Part_Number='{$_POST['Part_Number']}'"`

Comment: And here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: The database has over 1,000,000 different custom parts so I don't see the point in using a prepared query

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thank You so much!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using post in your ajax your values will be in the $_POST global in your PHP script.

change

`"SELECT * FROM nipple_list where Part_Number='$myPartNumber'"`

to

`"SELECT * FROM nipple_list where Part_Number='{$_POST['Part_Number']}'"`

Also you're at risk of a sql injection, you should be using prepared queries. 
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: I set on MySQL that the user "guest" has only the Select privilege for only that table and I have limited the amount of connections is that a good thing to do?

Comment: @ChasePrice in general the principle of least privilege is a good policy, but I don't think it's going stop everything in all cases. Do yourself a favor and just use prepared queries. It's quick and painless if you start using them from the beginning.

Comment: Okay Thanks, I really appreciate all the help!!